Result check of a functional derivative
For quantum chemistry problems, I need to understand functional derivative. I have begun to learn them a few days ago. So, my skill is very low.
In a exercise, I tried to calculate the functional derivative of :
$F[f] = \int dx \int dy \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}g(x,y)$
And I found :
$-\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}(\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y})$
It took me a while to find this result. Thus, I have many related questions. Firstly, is this result correct ? Indeed, I am not sure of this solution. So, I wonder if there is a simple mean to check result in a general way(for example with example functions or simple numerical approximations).
Moreover, I tried to search a table of functional derivative on the web (Google search : "functional derivative table"). I was surprised because I have not found anything. There are plenty of tables of derivatives for functions but not for functional derivative. So I wonder if such tables exist ?
Thanks for answer.
 Edit 1 
After Abezhiko's answer, I corrected my error.
And I found the good result
$-[2
g(x,y)\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}+
\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}+
\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}
]$

Since $f$ depends on several variables, the functional derivative is given by
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta f} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \vec{\nabla} \cdot \frac{\partial L}{\partial\vec{\nabla}f},
$$
where $L$ is the "Lagrangian" associated to
$$
F[f] = \int L\left(\vec{r},f(\vec{r}),\vec{\nabla}f(\vec{r})\right) \mathrm{d}^n\vec{r}
$$
and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec{\nabla}f}$ corresponds to the "gradient" with respect to $\vec{\nabla}f$. In the present case, one has $L = f_xf_yg$, where the indices denote partial derivatives. In consequence, one gets :
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta f} 
   = - \vec{\nabla} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} f_yg \\ f_xg \end{pmatrix} 
   = - \partial_x(f_yg) - \partial_y(f_xg) 
   = - \left(f_xg_y + f_yg_x + 2f_{xy}g\right)
$$
Unfortunately, few tables are available in comparison with the usual derivative; having said that, functional derivatives consist of a bunch of usual derivatives, in such a way that no specific table is really needed. Finally, there is no real technique to check the result, but you will be able to "guess" its expected general structure from the Lagrangian after some training.

Thanks a lot. I have corrected my error. I used a method that needs a lot of calculation steps  ( $\delta f(x) = \epsilon \delta (x-x0)$ and calculation of lim $\epsilon$ ->0 ). So, I have done an error (of course) in a step. I appreciate your method that is very convenient and direct. Where can I find a justification of this "Lagrangian method" ?

@Stef1611  Any physics textbook about lagrangian mechanics contains an introduction on calculus of variations with such treatments.
